# Can't find .classpath file in Eclipse, need to fix jarlist.cache error

Tags: android, eclipse

My console has been complaining that it can't find bin/jarlist.cache. Apparently this is a common problem and can be fixed by editing the .classpath file...however I can't seem to find that either. It isn't in the top level directory.

I have been following instructions from this blog:

http://nu-art-software-development-tips.blogspot.com/2012/03/adt-17-update-build-issues.html

Comment: .classpath is a hidden file by default. and is always under root project folder if the actual project is created/imported in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to yorkw and his comment, that was the answer:

> `.classpath` is a hidden file by default. and is always under root project folder if the actual project is created/imported in Eclipse.